# In the randrange function of random module in python is the upper limit specified in the randrange function included or excluded?

Tags: python, random

```
import random
l = []
for i in range(50):
    l.append(random.randint(1, 100))
print(l)
```

Now in the list of 50 random numbers is there a possibility ever of 100 being included?

Comment: Did you try? Did you read the documentation? Why are you doubting whether the upper limit is included?

Comment: It's actually easier to find the right part of the docs than it is to ask a question on Stack Overflow. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

"`random.randint(a, b)`
Return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`"

This means, that in your case 1 and 100 are included.